# Iteration of List<String> with modyfing String

Tags: java, string, collections

I can't modyfing element of List this way:

```
for (String s : list)
{
   s = "x" + s;
}
```

After execution this code elements of this list are unchanged
How to achieve iteration with modyfing through List in the simplest way.

Answer (score 17):

Since `String` objects are immutable, you cannot change the values you're iterating over. Furthermore, you cannot modify the list you're iterating over in such a loop. The only way to do this is to iterate over the list indexes with a standard loop or to use the `ListIterator` interface:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    list.set(i, "x" + list.get(i));
}

for (ListIterator i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
    i.set("x" + i.next());
}
```

Comment: No, using the list index is not the only way and accessing e.g. a long linked list with an elements index may perform very poorly. If you want to iterate and at the same time modify a list, using an Iterator or ListIterator is better.

Comment: so I back here as I've thought to standard loop.

Comment: @jarnbjo: You're right; I wasn't done yet. I included both methods.

Comment: @j2j: No, you can iterate; it's just not as simple -- see my second code sample.

Comment: @Gabe: Too bad that stackoverflow has turned to be about being the first one to answer just to harvest reputation points. It doesn't seem to matter if the answer is correct anymore.

Comment: -1. The first sentence is wrong.  This bug is not related to string immutability.

Comment: @finnw: Please point out which part is wrong. Surely you don't believe that strings are mutable? And, being immutable, surely you don't believe that you can change their values, right? If the OP has a `List<StringBuffer>`, he could easily do `s.insert(0, "x");` because a `StringBuffer` is mutable.

Comment: @Gabe, The problem (in the question) is that the OP is trying to modify the *List* through a normal Iterator, which of course does not work.  Your `ListIterator` example solves this.  The OP *might* also be confused about `String` immutability but that is not important (because it does not suggest a solution) - The List still needs to be modified.  Referring to `String` immutability just introduces more confusion.

Comment: @finnw: The *root* of the problem is that `String` is immutable. Had the OP been using a `List<StringBuffer>`, this question would have never shown up in the first place. Whether the OP is "trying" to mutate a string or modify a list is not a question we can answer because he could think that `s = "x" + s;` mutates the string just as easily as he could think that it modifies the list.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable beasts, so I can recommend to follow this philosophy and create new list instead modifying one:

```
List<String> mappedList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String s : list) {
    mappedList.add("x" + s);
}
```

I believe, that this will make your code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: The list is modifiable, so there is no need to create a new one.

Comment: @finnw: you can just pretend that it's not modifiable :) or if you want, you can make it unmodifiable like this: `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`. I just encourage in this answer to write more side-effect free code.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    for(final ListIterator<String> iter = lst.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        final String s = iter.next();
        iter.set(s + "x");
    }
    System.out.println(lst);
}
```

Comment: Why declare an extra local variable `s`, and why make it `final`?

Comment: @aioobe: Out of habit; I make it a point to declare everything as `final` unless needed otherwise. Similarly with variables. Plus I love making those who do premature optimization cringe. ;)

Comment: I always declare a variable to contain the result of `Iterator.next()` at the top of the block, to avoid bugs where `next()` is not called or is called more than once in the body of the loop.

Comment: @finnw: My rule of thumb is to give variables the *lowest* possible visibility. Declaring the variable at the top of the block makes it visible to the block plus the other code that follows.

Comment: Some people like the extra clutter

Comment: @Steve: Whatever rocks your boat or something like that... :)

Answer (score 2):

Java strings are immutable, hence they cannot be modified. Further, if you wish to modify a list use the iterator interface.

Comment: The only modification the Iterator interface allows is deletion. The ListIterator interface, on the other hand, has set() and add() methods.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out:

- You can't modify strings in Java, so `s = "x" + s` will create a new string (which will not be contained in the list)
- Even if you could, the variable `s` is a local variables, which, when assigned to, does not affect the values contained in the list.

The solution is in this case to use a `StringBuilder` which represents a string which you *can* actually modify, or to use a `ListIterator` as @Michael Borgwardt and @jarnbjo points out.

---

Using a `StringBuilder`:

```
List<StringBuilder> someStrings = new LinkedList<StringBuilder>();
someStrings.add(new StringBuilder("hello"));
someStrings.add(new StringBuilder("world"));

for (StringBuilder s : someStrings)
    s.insert(0, "x");
```

---

Using a `ListIterator`:

```
List<String> someStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
someStrings.add("hello");
someStrings.add("world");

for (ListIterator<String> iter = someStrings.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    iter.set("x" + iter.next());
```

[ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/8Powp)

Comment: I prefer to use `for` with iterators (split across multiple lines). `while` i much the same, but the iterator has an overlarge scope. And braces, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you're just modifying the local copy of the String. A better alternative would be to use the iterator of the list, and replace the current position of the list.

Edit, Oops, way to slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a `String` element of a `List` that way, but a `StringBuilder` would work just fine:

```
for (StringBuilder sb : list) sb.append("x");
```

The same is true for other primitive vs reference situations and the for-each loop.  In the loop, the `Iterable` is immutable, but the state of items in it is not - primitives (like `String`) do not have state and hence you're only modifying a local copy, but references can have state and hence you can mutate them via any mutator methods they might have (e.g., `sb.append("x")`).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, use `replaceAll()`

```java
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(myStrings));
serialsList.replaceAll(s -> "x" + s);
```