# Don't understand why the ForEach command isn't working

Tags: c#

I am wanting to trim any white space off a collection of strings. I used the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone explain why?

```
result.ForEach(f => f = f.Trim());
```

Comment: Similar (but for Java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851663/iteration-of-liststring-with-modyfing-string

Comment: Only use "ForEach" and "foreach" to *read* from a list; as you've discovered, it doesn't work well to *write* to a list. As an alternative solution, could you trim the string *before* it goes into the list? Then you don't even need to do this operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't work because you are assigning a new string reference to a local variable. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
result = result.Select(f => f.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - I got me on the right track, but I did it as follows... result = result.ConvertAll(f => f.Trim());

Comment: @Mark - That should be slightly more efficient. Of course you sacrifice the versatility of `Select` but if you need a `List<T>` that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-assigning the argument variable inside the scope of the lambda. It's a collapsed form of:

```
foreach(string value in myList)
{
    Lambda(value);
}

void Lambda(string input)
{
    input = input.Trim();
}
```

The simplest way would probably be to use a projection:

```
myList = myList.Select(str => str.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Rex - Is there a way to achieve what I am wanting and still use the lamda expression?

Comment: Thanks for the help - I gave you +1

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` doesn't give you write access to the underlying collection, it only iterates through it, which means your change isn't stored back into the collection.

You can do two things:

1. Produce a new collection

   ```
   var newResult = result.Select(f => f.Trim()).ToList();
   ```
2. Use a normal for-loop and change the original collection

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < result.Count; index++)
       result[index] = result[index].Trim();
   ```