# change ArrayList<String> content on java

Tags: java

I'm trying to change the value on an `ArrayList<String>` called this way

```
mails.forEach(mail -> {
     mail = "my_new_value";
     System.out.println(mail);//here the value is correct
});
```

But outside the loop mails has the original value,I thought that on Java every thing is passed by a reference,what is the problem?

Comment: "*[...] on Java every thing is passed by a reference [...]*" - Java is call-by-value. Always.

Comment: If you really want to replace every value in the original `ArrayList<String>` by a single value, you could simply use `Collections.fill(yourList, "the value");` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill(java.util.List,%20T)))

Comment: This is exactly what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851663/iteration-of-liststring-with-modyfing-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is roughly the same as:

```
for (String mail : mails) {
    mail = "my_new_value";
}
```

As you can see, you're changing the variable `mail` to refer to a new object (i.e., the String literal). This does not change the original String inside the list!

Comment: "*Your code is roughly the same as [...]*" - OP's code is - in some sense - a superset of this code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at Java's Map transformation in the Stream API.

You could do the following:

***Code***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");

        list = list.stream()
                .map(value -> value.toUpperCase())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

***Output***

```
[HELLO, WORLD]
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you're trying to do here is:

```
mails.replaceAll(v -> "my_new_value");
```